VSCode Autocomplete has too many suggestions
I am relatively new to using VSCode and whenever I try to use the autocomplete function I am met with 30 different options. Whenever I watch a coding tutorial I only see them have a few, actually good suggestions. Here is an example of me trying to write a simple console.log function in js.
I tried installing some extensions but they haven't worked.
